# db2 update dbm cfg fails with error: SQL5133N. Specified value: "0". Configuration parameter name: "fcm_buffer_size"

Tags: db2, keytool, truststore, dbm

I am trying to load SSL certificate from java keystore to db2 dbm.

I did below steps:
Step 1: List certificates in truststore

```
$ keytool -list -v -keystore db-truststore
Enter keystore password:  
Keystore type: jks
Keystore provider: SUN

Your keystore contains 2 entries

Alias name: caintermediate
Creation date: May 24, 2018
Entry type: trustedCertEntry
...
...
Alias name: carootcert
Creation date: May 24, 2018
Entry type: trustedCertEntry
```

Step 2: Exported these certificates to files

```
keytool -export -alias carootcert -keystore db-truststore -file rootcert.pem
Enter keystore password:  
Certificate stored in file <rootcert.pem>

keytool -export -alias caintermediate -keystore db-truststore -file intermediatecert.pem
Enter keystore password:  
Certificate stored in file <intermediatecert.pem>
```

Step 3: created key database:

```
gsk8capicmd_64 -keydb -create -db "dbclient.kdb" -pw "passw0rd" -stash
```

Step 4: Added certificate files to key database

```
gsk8capicmd_64 -cert -add -db /full-path/dbclient.kdb -pw passw0rd -label carootcert -file rootcert.pem
gsk8capicmd_64 -cert -add -db /full-path/dbclient.kdb -pw passw0rd -label caintermediate -file intermediatecert.pem
```

Step 5: Added catalog:

```
db2 => catalog TCPIP NODE phdbdev  REMOTE  bldbz173038.cloud.dst.ibm.com  SERVER 60443  SECURITY SSL
DB20000I  The CATALOG TCPIP NODE command completed successfully.
DB21056W  Directory changes may not be effective until the directory cache is 
refreshed.
db2 => catalog DATABASE phdbdev  AT NODE phdbdev  AUTHENTICATION SERVER
DB20000I  The CATALOG DATABASE command completed successfully.
DB21056W  Directory changes may not be effective until the directory cache is 
refreshed.
```

Step 6: Updated gdm

```
db2 update dbm cfg using SSL_CLNT_KEYDB /full-path/dbclient.kdb 
SQL5133N  The configuration parameter was not updated because the specified 
value is not valid.  Specified value: "0".  Configuration parameter name: 
"fcm_buffer_size".
```

Further investigation as suggested:

```
$ db2level
DB21085I  This instance or install (instance name, where applicable: "vizeet") 
uses "64" bits and DB2 code release "SQL11010" with level identifier 
"0201010F".
Informational tokens are "DB2 v11.1.0.0", "s1606081100", "DYN1606081100AMD64", 
and Fix Pack "0".
Product is installed at "/home/vizeet/sqllib".

$ db2 get dbm cfg | grep 'Node type'
     Node type = Enterprise Server Edition with local and remote clients

$ db2 get dbm cfg | grep FCM
 Number of FCM buffers                 (FCM_NUM_BUFFERS) = AUTOMATIC(4096)
 FCM buffer size                       (FCM_BUFFER_SIZE) = 0
 Number of FCM channels               (FCM_NUM_CHANNELS) = AUTOMATIC(2048)
 FCM parallelism                       (FCM_PARALLELISM) = AUTOMATIC(1)
```

db-truststore works properly with db2 drivers.

Unable to resolve this issue. Kindly help.

Comment: Your question concerns configuration and not programming. Use dba.stackexchange.com  for configuration matters.  Edit your question to add the output of the `db2level` command,  and to add the output of these commands `db2 get dbm cfg | grep 'Node type' `  and also  `db2 get dbm cfg | grep FCM` .  Don't use comments to add new facts, but instead edit your question.

Comment: "fcm_buffer_size" default is 32768 but something changed it to 0. Revert that change. Other changes might be needed, if non-root installed. Follow the documentation for details.